# Rails Devise - Separate confirm_within time for reconfirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In the `config/initializers/devise.rb` I have set `config.reconfirmable = true` and am now able to use Devises process of changing emails with sending out a confirmation mail, that contains a confirmation token.

I am also aware that I can set the expiration period of devise tokens with `config.confirm_within = 2.weeks`.

But this seems to be a global options for both confirmation tokens:

1. the token that is sent in the registration confirmation mail
2. the token that is sent in the email change confirmation mail.

I can't find anything in the documentation to set different expiration dates for those two tokens. I am searching for something like this `config.confirm_reconfirmable_within = 3.days`

Am I missing something here or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My short answer is it is not possible in the default Devise.

As the [official doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable) lists, `confirm_within` is the only related parameter for it.

I guess few users want to set different expiration periods for confirmation emails and so it is perhaps not surprising the parameter is not configurable about the point…

It seems it is controlled in `Confirmable#confirm` defined in `vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-**/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb` . So, you can redefine the method to suit your need if you wish.